# How can my Firebase authentication page handle existing and non-existing users?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native-navigation, react-native-firebase

I have this basic react native authentication page set up with firebase phone authentication. The verification code is successfully sent to the user, but when i enter and validate the given code, my app never navigates to the corresponding page (Home for existing user, CreateProfile for a new user). This is most likely due to an error in the following snippets. Does anybody have an idea?

```
const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("");
const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState("");
const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = useState("");
const [info, setInfo] = useState("");


  const handleVerifyVerificationCode = async () => {
    try {
      const credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId,
        verificationCode
      );
      const result = await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);

      if (result.user) {
        const userExists = await checkIfUserExists(result.user);
        if (userExists) {
          navigation.navigate("Home");
        } else {
          navigation.navigate("CreateProfile");
        }
      } else {
        setInfo("Error: User cancelled sign-in process");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === "auth/code-expired") {
        setInfo(
          "Error: The verification code has expired. Please request a new one."
        );
      } else {
        console.log("Error:", error);
        setInfo(`Error : ${error.message}`);
      }
    }
  };

  const checkIfUserExists = async (user) => {
    try {
      const userRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
      const userDoc = await getDoc(userRef);

      if (!userDoc.exists()) {
        const data = {
          uid: user.uid,
          phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber,
        };
        await setDoc(userRef, data);
        navigation.navigate("CreateProfile", { user: data });
      } else {
        navigation.navigate("Home", { user: userDoc.data() });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error checking user existence: ", error);
      setInfo(
        "Error: There was a problem checking the user's existence. Please try again."
      );
      throw error;
    }
  };
```

I get the following errors, and copilot doesn't seem to find a workaround...

> LOG 0 ERROR [2024-01-27T12:31:58.103Z] @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.7.2): INTERNAL UNHANDLED ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined at isSafari
> 0): TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined at isSafari
> 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined at isSafari

Comment: Did you already step through the code in a debugger, to see precisely which line doesn't do what you expect it to do? So: set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line. If you do this, what is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @JeCho You could downgrade the firebase dependency, there are bugs in 10.7.2 try using 10.7.1 [Check this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7962),

Comment: @ALFaizAhmed This actually fixed it. Kind of frustrating when your code is not working because of external errors so thank you very much for the help. Downgrading to Firebase 10.7.1 did the trick.

Comment: @JeCh0 Your Upvote on my comment will be helpful for others Devs, Cheers! 